# how do can I get svn_cat to work?

Tags: php, svn

I am new to php, and I am trying to read the contents of a file that is on svn. svn_cat() looks like it will do what I want... but it says that I am trying to use an undefined function. is there something that I have to "include" or "require" can someone tell me what that would look like... and what it is referred to as. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the svn module compiled into php. You can find installation instructions [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/svn.installation.php)